# Importing Gerber files into Fritzing

Tags: gerber, import, fritzing

Is it possible to import a gerber file into Fritzing or do I need to change the format? If I need to change the format, what do I change it too?

Comment: Then what program would you suggest? Screaming something sucks doesn't exactly help.

Comment: The caps are for emphasis, not intending to scream. In retrospect I probably should have used **bold**, not caps. Anyway, Fritzing is a toy, and it's not really even good at being that. I suggest using a real tool like Eagle or KiCAD (both of which are free, though Eagle is limited), or if this is a more serious project that warrants a paid package, try something like Altium

Comment: Thank you, I am using Altium but I am not yet familiar with it so it is very frustrating when I just want to make a simple board. I have KiCAD and Eagle downloaded to try out it was just Fritzing since it was the one I had been using the most recent in my spare time so that's what I went with for this question. I do agree that it is way to simple for real board work, but I just want something simple for now.

Comment: Altium definitely has a steep learning curve, that's for sure. Once you learn how to use it, though, board design is a breeze. Before Altium I used Eagle exclusively for my own boards, though I tried dozens of different packages. Eagle was definitely my preferred tool though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Gerber is in essence a file that tells a lithography machine how to move to produce the shapes on every layer of a printed circuit board.

Fritzing, on the other hand, is a schematic capture tool of sorts. There's no way back from a pcb layout to a proper schematic, since that layout contains zero information on the components that are supposed to populate that board.

And even if there were any such information, then going back from a layout to an *intelligible* schematic is still an unsolved problem, and probably will be forever.

Comment: Thank you, now I just need to know how to make a plug board with contacts in Fritzing.

Comment: fritzing can autoroute schematics, not just PCBs...